# Estimating the growth rate of points in a hypercubic lattice

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Take the hypercubic lattice $\mathbb{Z}^d$. Consider a ball $B^{1}_{R}$ with radius R in the 1-norm (also known as the Taxicab or sum norm) around the origin. I am trying to understand the number of points added to the ball when the radius is increased by one, which is known as the growth rate of the graph.

My goal is to determine if there is an easy way to prove that the growth rate is exponential, or equivalently, if the number of points in the set $B^{1}_{R+1} \setminus B^{1}_{R}$ is less than $C_{2} 2^{d \cdot R}$ but more than $C_{1} 2^{d \cdot R}$, where $C_{1}$ and $C_{2}$ are constants that may depend only on the dimension $d$.

I have tried the following:

1. I have used the fact that all norms on $\mathbb{Z}^d$ are equivalent and found some constants $c_{1}$, $c_{2}$ such that: $B^{1}_{R+1} \setminus B^{1}_{R} \subset B^{2}_{c_{1}(R+1)} \setminus B^{2}_{c_{2}R}$, where $B^{2}_{c_{1}(R+1)}$ denotes the ball around the origin with radius $(R + 1) \cdot c_{1}$ in the Euclidean norm.
2. I have used the fact that $|B^{1}_{R+1} \setminus B^{1}_{R}| \leq |B^{2}_{c_{1} (R+1)}| - |B^{2}_{c_{2} R}|$.
3. I have attempted to calculate/estimate the number of points in $|B^{2}_{k}|$ for a given $k$ using the volume of the ball in $\mathbb{R}^d$, however, it is proving to be more challenging than I initially expected.

Obviously we can try to calculate the number of points in $B^{1}_{R+1} \setminus B^{1}_{R}$ with Combinatorial Techniques, but it seems really elaborate.

My questions are:

Am I on the right path?
Am I missing something?
Are there easier ways to solve this problem?

I would like to express my gratitude to everyone who takes the time to help me with my question. Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

**Simple answer**

The growth rate is polynomial. All points in $B_R^1$ fit inside an axis-aligned hypercube centered at the origin whose sides span $2R+1$ lattice points, so $$|B_R^1|\le (2R+1)^d.$$

This further implies that $|B_{R+1}^1\setminus B_R^1|\le |B^1_{R+1}|\le (2R+3)^d$, so you only add polynomially many points as you increment $R$.

**Exact answer**

The combinatorics for computing $|B_{R}^1\setminus B_{R-1}^1|$ are actually not too bad. This is the set of integer points $(x_1,\dots,x_d)$ for which
$$
|x_1|+\dots+|x_d|=R.
$$
Let us first count the number of such points which have exactly $k$ coordinates which are nonzero, for each $k\in \{0,\dots,d\}$. We can choose which coordinates are nonzero in $\binom{d}k$ ways. Next, we choose the values of $|x_i|$ for each $i$ that is a nonzero coordinate. We are counting the number of ways to write $R$ as an ordered sum of $k$ positive integers, which is $\binom{R-1}{k-1}$. This can be shown with a stars-and-bars type argument; starting with a line of $R$ stones, with $R-1$ gaps between them, choose $k-1$ of those gaps, and place a barrier there. The barriers create $k$ contiguous groups of stones summing to $R$. All that remains is to choose the signs of the nonzero coordinates in $2^k$ ways. Finally, summing over $k$, the number of points is
$$
|B_{R}^1\setminus B_{R-1}^1|=\sum_{k=0}^d \binom{d}k\binom{R-1}{k-1}2^k.
$$

This even makes sense when $k=0$. The common convention is to define $\binom{n}k=0$ whenever $k<0$ or $k>n$ (at least when $k$ is an integer). This does not work with the factorial definition of $\binom nk$, but it works with the combinatorial definition of $\binom nk$. You can define $\binom nk$ to be "the number of size $k$-subsets of an $n$-element set." This definition implies $\binom{R-1}{-1}=0$, because the number of subsets with size $-1$ must be zero, as it is impossible for a size to be negative.

Therefore, the $k=0$ term is zero, which agrees with the fact that there are *zero* ways to write $R$ as a sum of zero integers, when $R>0$. When $R=0$, there actually is one way to write $0$ as a sum of zero integers, namely, the [empty sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_sum).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I now understand what went wrong with me. However, some questions arise with regards to your exact answer, as the stars-and-bars type argument was not known to me before. 1) "Let us first count the number of such points which have exactly k coordinates that are nonzero, for each k∈{0,…,d}": I think that this doesnt makes sense for k=0 because then there is no possibility to write R as an ordered sum of k positive integers, and also, for k=0 the sum on the right side ist $...\binom{R-1}{-1}...$ and I don't know how this is defined.

Comment: @Estudante I explained in an edit. Alternatively, you could just replace $\sum_{k=0}^d$ in my answer with $\sum_{k=\color{blue}1}^d$, and it would work just as well.